# Grow tree and animate

Tags: animation

I'm trying to build a tree using multiple tiers (circle, extrude, scale), like a pine tree and their layers, and then animate it.  Any suggestions on how to proceed??
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GKes2FYy0E&list=PL0RtAku-eLdMb4gFVgLgJxgC8BkxpcyMR&index=10
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svErsjEJEo8&list=PL0RtAku-eLdMb4gFVgLgJxgC8BkxpcyMR&index=17

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the array modifier to stack the shapes you described on top of each other. And, then, use the curve modifier (but don't apply it) to bend the stack in order to make an animation of the wind blowing on the tree like this:

[image: stack animation]

Now, just add the top, the trunk and setup the materials:

[image]